# org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route :because of Static method with name: methodA() not found on class:

Tags: routes, mockito, apache-camel, spring-boot-test

I am writing **camel route test** using **mockito** and **camelTestSupport**, but the test is failing with below **error**:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodNotFoundException: Static method with name: methodA not found on class: .service.impl.ServiceImpl
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.DefaultBeanProcessorFactory.createBeanProcessor
```

The method is present in service impl, and is defined as below:

```
public Object methodA(@Headers Map headers, @Body String payload) {
  return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: Any suggestions on the above issue?